# Is there any tool for GAC management?

Tags: .net, assemblies, global-assembly-cache

Is there any GUI to view, add, delete assemblies in Global Assembly Cache?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/430568/A-GAC-Manager-Utility-and-API  works pretty good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also [WinGAC](http://iridescence.no/post/WinGacaGUIfortheGlobalAssemblyCache.aspx) which I've seen people use. Seemed to do a good job

CodePlex has a project called [Win GAC](http://wingac.codeplex.com/) as well but I don't have experience with it. It hasn't been updated since 2008 and says it supports up to .NET 3.5 but I have a feeling it would handle 4.0 just fine.

Comment: It probably doesn't, the GAC got moved for 4.0

Comment: @Hans Passant. Good point! I was thinking the docs had just never been updated but, yeah, that would break it alright. It's open source though so that should be a minor fix.

Comment: [Gacbroswer](http://gacbrowser.blogspot.in/2008/03/gac-browser-introduction.html) (Open Source) supports Framework 4.0

Answer (score 5):

You can also try [GACAdmin](http://www.unifize.nl/gacadmin) It also supports `.NET 4.`

Comment: [Gacbrowser](http://gacbrowser.blogspot.in/2008/03/gac-browser-introduction.html) is similar software but it doesn't support adding (registering) new assembly.

Comment: The link is broken.